# How to transfer variable from one php file to another?

Tags: php, html, mysql

This question will probably be marked as duplicate, but I didnt find other answers helpful.

I am creating a site where user could answer multiple type of questions. Thus i wrote code so the corresponding html template will appear, according to type of question. Right now my php code is following:

```
<?php
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
$_SESSION['pollid']=(int) $_GET['pollid'];
$questions = array();
$answer = $_POST['answer'];
if (!isset($_SESSION['answering'])) {
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * from katse_kysimused where kysimustik_id="' . $_SESSION['pollid'] . '"');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $questions[] = $row['kysimus'];
        }
    $_SESSION['answering']['questions'] = $questions;
    $_SESSION['answering']['index'] = 0;
}
    $x = $_SESSION['answering']['index'];
    $result3 = mysql_query('SELECT tyyp_id FROM katse_kysimused where kysimus= "' . $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x] . '"');
    $type = mysql_result($result3, 0);
    if ($type=='3'){
        echo $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x];
        $result4 = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus_id FROM katse_kysimused where kysimus= "' . $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x] . '"');
        $question_id = mysql_result($result4, 0);
        $result5 = mysql_query('SELECT * from katse_valik_vastused where kysimus_id="' . $question_id . '"');
        if($result5 === FALSE) {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result5)) {
            $options[] = $row['vasuts'];
        }
        foreach($options as $option=>$option_value) {
            echo $option_value;
}
        }

    if ($type=='1'){
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://localhost/Praks/tekstkysimusele_vastamine2.php'>";
        }
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $result2 = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus_id FROM katse_kysimused where kysimus= "' . $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x -1] . '"');
    $q_id = mysql_result($result2, 0);
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO katse_vastused2 (id, vastus,kysimus_id, vastustik_id) VALUES (NULL,"' . $answer . '","' . $q_id . '","1")');
    }
$_SESSION['answering']['index']++;
?>
```

And what I want to do is to make following html template appear, when $type=='1'.

```
<?php
echo $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x];
?>
<html>
<br>
<form method="post" action="answering.php">
<input type="text" name="answer" style="width:300px; height:150px;"><br>
<input name= "submit" type="submit" value="Vasta">
</form>
</html>
```

My question is, how could I make it appear with question. Right now $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x]; is undefined.How could I transfer it from first file to second?

Comment: Look out for SQL Injection.

Comment: How do you call the second file ?

Comment: I call it 'tekstkysimusele_vastamine2.php'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SESSION['answering']['questions'];`
contains a **list** of items, you have to specify which one should be displayed.

In case you need the last index, this is simple (and ugly) solution:

```
<?php
    $last_index = count($_SESSION['answering']['questions']) -1;
    echo $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$last_index];
?>
<html>
<br>
<form method="post" action="answering.php">
<input type="text" name="answer" style="width:300px; height:150px;"><br>
<input name= "submit" type="submit" value="Vasta">
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$x` and then try it:

```
echo $_SESSION['answering']['questions'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Now my second file is following:

```
<?php
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
$x = $_SESSION['answering']['index'];
echo $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x];
?>
<html>
<br>
<form method="post" action="answering.php">
<input type="text" name="answer" style="width:300px; height:150px;"><br>
<input name= "submit" type="submit" value="Vasta">
</form>
</html>
```